# How to check if an object is an Express instance?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm using typescript to check if an app returned by Express() is an Express instance.

I'm doing this:

```
import Express from "express"

const app = Express()

console.log(app instanceof Express)
```

But it is always returning `false`

Comment: I just want to know for which purpose you are trying to check express instance?

Comment: I dont think you can check it this way, when you do typeof, then you will get "function" for both. It depends on the purpose what you want to achieve by doing this. One way to have a basic check is to call path() on app, it will either return "" or some path if its set for that app.  This is just basic and that too if its under control, otherwise someone can create a dummy object and create path function under it to bypass this.

Comment: I'm developing a tool which inspects all the routes. It needs to receive the express application so I would like to manage the case when it receives another thing that is not the express server instance. https://github.com/diegoulloao/router-dex

Comment: I need to check it in a more conventional way. I don't know which paths the express server will contain.

Comment: Create a array of properties/methods a typical express app has, and check for this properties on the object you receive. There is no `app instanceof Express` check.

Comment: I thought that... should work but I don't like the methodology

Comment: I answered with the solution I chose.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `instanceof` way to check it.

So finally I did:

```js
if ( !app.hasOwnProperty("listen") || typeof app.listen !== "function" ) {
  // So it's not an Express instance
}
```

Rest is to trust in god.